# Children's CGI show about people flying around on an airship between sky islands

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I've been trying to identify this show for a while, however my memories of it are fuzzy.

I watched it at some point between 2003-2012, likely on one of the following channels in England: CBBC, CITV, CBEEBIES (unlikely but possible). It may also have been on other non-Sky channels at the time. It didn't look out of place aesthetically, so I assume its from roughly that time, however it could have been older.

I recall that a family, I think(?) -- I believe there was a sister and brother + more -- travelled on a sky ship between sky islands. If it had a main storyline, it was incomprehensible by the airing schedule.
There is one scene that sticks in my mind, however.

In one episode, the sister takes part in some sort of martial arts (the name skyfu comes to mind, but that may have been a joke in the show?) challenge that I believe was some sort of kata rather than a fight; it at least seemed like one. During this, they run at each other, then jump and essentially run into the air by pushing off from each other's feet, with it basically being a mirror. This came off as a really dumb scene, even for child me.

I don't believe that it's *Skyland* or *Storm Hawks*, having skipped through them / checked their wiki pages, but may be wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Episode S01E04 of ***[Storm Hawks](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1043820/)*** (2007–2009), titled "[The Code](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1055151/?ref_=ttep_ep4)", has a scene matching your description, including the use of the term "Sky Fu" to refer to the martial art being showcased.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_Hawks):

> ***Storm Hawks* is set on a fictional world called Atmos, a largely mountainous world consisting of scattered, towering, plateau-like land masses known as terras.** Directly below the terras lie the Wastelands, the most dangerous area of Atmos, with infernal fires and wicked creatures. **Because of the geography, travel is mostly dependent on flight.** The technology of Atmos is based around energy-generating crystals, used to power the various devices in the series. Patrolling the skies of Atmos are the Squadrons, groups of warriors who pilot motorcycle-like vehicles called Skimmers that can semi-transform into flying machines. Each Squadron is led by a Sky Knight and these warriors are loosely managed by the Sky Knight Council.
>
> In the backstory of the series, an evil ruler named Master Cyclonis and her servants, the Cyclonians, threatened Atmos. The original Storm Hawks led the Squadrons in a war against them, but were betrayed and defeated by one of their own (later known as The Dark Ace). Ten years later, **the main characters of the series stumble upon the wreckage of the Storm Hawks' carrier, the Condor, and unofficially take on the Storm Hawks name in the hopes of becoming Sky Knights themselves, despite not being old enough to even legally fly the vehicle.**

From the [Storm Hawks Wiki](https://stormhawks.fandom.com/wiki/Piper):

> **As she demonstrates in Episode 4, "The Code," Piper can move fluently through the motions of Sky Fu with ease and grace,** much to the amusement of Aerrow and disbelief of Finn who states, "Where'd she learn that?"

You can view the scene in question at around the 11:26 mark in the video below:

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that, I must have only searched sky-fu and skyfu, thats definitely the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have been “Laputa, Castle in the Sky”?
By Studio Ghibli

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be what the OP was looking for, i.e. the ways in which it matches the show described in the question. Also note that the [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/265811/122024) was marked as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by the OP, as denoted by the green tick next to it, which indicates that the OP believes that answer is correct.

Comment: *Laputa, Castle in the Sky* is not CGI.